# How to get tags from different blog?

Tags: tags, switch-to-blog

Its very easy to use on a blog, it works standallone:

[image]

but what about if those tags comes from another blog? I cant see the way to switch_to_blog() or something. I also must not be writing into the core...

Comment: There's no context here. Where do you want to get tags from a different blog? When editing a post? You can't tag posts with tags from another blog so you would need to copy them first and that's not supported by the standard post editor. You should elaborate on what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: There's no code in your question, can you add more context to your question? Where is the screenshot taken from? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: it is from "editing post". No source code indeed, because Im just using the basic core-functions